# Getting base path in URL

Tags: php

**code**:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/product/filename.html';
echo parse_url($url);
```

**output**:

```
[scheme] => https
[host] => www.example.com
[path] => /path/to/product/filename.html
```

How do I get the current base path, that is:

`https://www.example.com/path/to/product/`

Comment: check this : https://eval.in/664072

Comment: @ElefantPhace I'm OP. And I did google/search, just didn't like the solutions. I'm still glad I asked so I found `dirname()`. And I never bother about the rep btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy

```
$basePath = dirname($url) . '/';
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/XGNDd

Comment: one liner solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/product/filename.html';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(pathinfo($url));
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => https://www.example.com/path/to/product
    [basename] => filename.html
    [extension] => html
    [filename] => filename
)
```

You can get the path as:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/product/filename.html';
$info = pathinfo($url);
echo $info['dirname']; //https://www.example.com/path/to/product
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
/**
     * Suppose, you are browsing in your localhost 
     * http://localhost/myproject/index.php?id=8
     */
    function getBaseUrl() 
    {
        // output: /myproject/index.php
        $currentPath = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

        // output: Array ( [dirname] => /myproject [basename] => index.php [extension] => php [filename] => index ) 
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($currentPath); 

        // output: localhost
        $hostName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 

        // output: http://
        $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://'?'https://':'http://';

        // return: http://localhost/myproject/
        return $protocol.$hostName.$pathInfo['dirname']."/";
    }
```

or easier with this:

```
echo "http://".dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```